# SCTP support for Linux kernel 3.3.4-5.fc17.x86_64

Tags: networking, kernel

I'm using Fedora 17 64-bit version, with Linux kernel version 3.3.4-5.fc17.x86_64.

I installed `lksctp` using `yum`.

```
sudo yum install lksctp-tools.x86_64
```

When I try to run

```
sctp_status -H 127.0.0.1 -P 10 -l
```

I'm getting this result:

```
Starting tests...


        *** socket: failed to create socket:  Protocol not supported ***
```

How can I resolve this problem? Why can't I start an SCTP server this way?

Comment: Is the `sctp` module loaded (`sudo modprobe sctp`). What does `checksctp` say?

Comment: checksctp says checksctp: Protocol not supported subo modprobe sctp FATAL: Module sctp not found.
but I when i try sudo modprobe xt_sctp it loads the driver dont know what that is.

Comment: xt_sctp is for the ability of netfilter (iptables) to recognize SCTP traffic. Maybe your sctp module is called something else, or maybe it's not compiled at all, or maybe it's available as a different package (maybe because it's all kernel). Does `sudo modprobe net_pf_2_proto_132` work? `grep SCTP /boot/config*`

Comment: No "sudo modprobe net_pf_2_proto_132" dint work